Can someone help me understand the grammar in this video?
https://www.instagram.com/p/C9Llhf7x0Lm/
I'm watching this video from a Latin American psychologist and I'm confused by some of the grammatical constructions. I think I understand everything she is saying but I don't why certain things are phrased the way they are.
For example when she says "Segundo, escucho música alegre que me gusta y que pueda cantar."
In the subordinate clause why is the first verb "me gusta" in the indicative but the second verb "pueda" in the subjunctive?
Also when she says, “El ejercicio...me ayuda a enfocarme en la actividad y en lo que siente mi cuerpo, así que me distraigo temporalmente de las preocupaciones y estresores para cuando esté más calmada poder resolverlas.” This sentence just feels very weirdly phrased and I don’t know how to translate it. “Exercise helps me focus on the activity and on what my body feels so I distract myself from my worries and stressors temporarily for when I am calmer to able to resolve it.”
Is that correct?
Thirdly when she says “Así que siempre, lo mejor es que estas técnicas vengan de un proceso de ensayo y error.”
Is the correct translation: “Like always, the best thing is that these techniques come from a process of trial and error?”

In all three cases, the speaker is discussing an action without asserting that the action is fact.

so that when  I'm calmer I'm able to resolve them. That's the bit you missed. que pueda cantar=that I might/could sing.

You seem to be having some difficulty understanding why the subjunctive mood is used in all three sentences:

Escucho música alegre que me gusta y que pueda cantar.

"gusta" means that the person does like that kind of music, and "pueda cantar" is used to express probability, something like "that I may be able to sing". If the person is positive about being able to sing that kind of music, then "puedo cantar" will be used.

El ejercicio...me ayuda a enfocarme en la actividad y en lo que siente mi cuerpo, así que me distraigo temporalmente de las preocupaciones y estresores para cuando esté más calmada poder resolverlas.

In this case, "esté" refers to a future ahead of the time referred to before.

Así que siempre, lo mejor es que estas técnicas vengan de un proceso de ensayo y error.

"Vengan" is used instead of "vienen" to mean that the best thing is for those techniques to be based on trial and error. If "vienen" were used, that would mean that those techniques always come from that process, something like "the good thing is that these techniques come from a process of trial and error."

might/could be able, not may here.
